# com.approuter.module.http.protocol.HttpConnectionException: Received Http Code:500

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, cast-iron

I am hitting Prod WSDL to get data by HTTP Post request. but it is running successfully like 1st, 2nd, 4th day and failed in 3rd, 5th day due to Error: Unable to connect to server after 5 attempts. Error is: com.approuter.module.http.protocol.HttpConnectionException: Received Http Code:500

```
ERROR:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
               at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
               at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
               at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
               at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
               at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
               at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
               at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
               at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
               at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:149)
               at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:110)
               at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:264)
               at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer.readLine(LoggingSessionInputBuffer.java:115)
               at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:98)
               at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:252)
               at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281)
               at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:247)
               at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:219)
               at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpClientSupport.java:147)
               at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
               at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:633)
               at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
               at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
               at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
               at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
               at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
               at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:290)
               at  com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:220)
               at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
               at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Check if the application is running. You can also look that logs to see what is going on. If application is taking too much time to response, you try increasing timeout.

Comment: aoolication is running, but i am hitting external system/wsdl sometime i am getting data and sometime not. getting timeout in failed case